# How to play sound on the server

Tags: javascript, php, server, speaker

It is possible to play sound on server?
I mean when client try to click the button from client computer, the sound will out from server speaker not client speaker.

I'm making on system to call customer and how to do it using only php program? Or it need something to do it?

Comment: To answer your question "Is it possible": yes it is. As for how: that's too broad a question. It all depends on what kind of server, what OS, what software you have available, what the sound is, etc. You'll need to be more specific to get a good answer.

Comment: Rack servers don't typically have soundcards, much less stereo speakers.

Comment: @zeterain Sorry, i forget it. How can i do it with php? Or it need something else to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the help of a realtime database like firebase or you need to listen to the changes in client-side and notify the server. The server needs to continuously poll the value.

Something Like (Worst way)[Wastes lot of resouces]:

**Client:**

```
<button onclick="send()"/>

//js
function send()
{
   window.location.replace("domain/alert.php?user=id");
}

//php
<?php
if(isset($_GET['user']))
{
   //update value in database
}
?>
```

**Server:**

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
</head>

//php
<?php
//check if value changed
if(valueChanged)
{
    echo '<script>playSound()</script>';
    //Print which user from database
}
?>

//js
function playSound()
{
    var audio = new Audio('https://www.soundsnap.com/streamers/play.php?id=1593757181.74:97b6d28b0a3677cf4dd417f0928f2147875686a6: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');
    audio.play();
    console.log("done");
}
```

Comment: You didn't consider AJAX to make the request? And how is the sound made here?

Comment: Sure... You can use ajax. But still the worst way as the server needs to constantly poll for the value. Better to use a realtime database.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've understood the question at all?

Comment: He wants to alert the user on other end. Just like food delivery app??

Comment: They want to play a sound on the machine the server is installed.

Comment: Exactly. When the client play the sound or trigger the sound button, the sound will out on server speaker not client speaker.

Comment: What about now? I added an mp3 to be played in server script.

Comment: No, they want their server to beeb, not the user's machine ...

Comment: Ok... I didnt find any solution for that till now.